# Get controller var from run.schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an EmberJS application. I want to make something like a global variable/function which will detect if user visited application from desktop computer or from mobile.
In main controller (controller/application.js) I have a code like this:

```
    Ember.Controller.extend({
       currentUser: 0,
       lastRemoteId: 0
    })
```

I need to add a variable or function like this:

```
    Ember.Controller.extend({
       ...,
       isMobile: function(){
          [code which detects if user visited from mobile device or not]
       }
    })
```

In main view (views/application.js) inside of didInsertElement I want to get this isMobile var. when I try to execute `this.controllerFor('application')` I receive an error: "undefined is not a function". Is it correct way to do like I did?

Answer (score 1):

The application controller is set as a property on the application view, you can access it using the getters.

```
var appController = this.get('controller');
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed like this:
I added code to the controller:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
    ... // some properties,
    mobileDetect: function () {
        return new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
    }.property(),
    actions: {
        ...
    }
}
```

And inside `didInsertElement` I have code like this:

```
this.get('controller.mobileDetect')
```

And I will receive `mobileDetect` object and able to execute its methods. For now it works